# Update WordPress and Advanced Custom Fields?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

WordPress Dashboard said that I should update WordPress, "Update wordpress to latest version 4.5.3".

But the plugin Advanced Custom Fields, currently v. 4.4.7, is only compatible with WordPress 4.5.0, it has not been updated in 2 months, compatibility with WordPress 4.5.3: Unknown.

Should I update WordPress and Advanced Custom Fields, or do I have to wait to update WordPress and therefore all other plugins I have activated.

Comment: Not really a question for SO, but yes, there were no breaking changes. You can upgrade

Answer (score 1):

The WordPress core version 4.5.3 is a [minor](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/about/release-cycle/version-numbering/) release and reserved for fixing security vulnerabilities and addressing critical bugs only.  These updates rarely break plugin functionality.  You should be OK to update the WordPress core.

When [updating WordPress](http://websynthesis.com/updating-wordpress/) core, it is advisable to backup your site first, update plugins next, and finally update the WordPress core.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Sure! you can update the plugin it won't affect your functionality